# Understanding branch and bound tree

Tags: integer-programming

[image]

How much information can be gleaned from the above? For example the objective value changed from 67.45 to 67.28, is there a way to know which simplex step was used to achieve that? It would mean $x_3$ is the entering variable so which is the leaving variable?